# enable to use tomtom search api in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

Been searching for a week now, The official  [documentation](https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-android-sdk/documentation-0) are not clear at all.

as mentioned there, the code

```
val searchServiceConnection = SearchServiceManager.createAndBind(context,
    searchServiceConnectionCallback)
```

should initialize the search API in the application. but it is not clear how to use it after this.

I installed and initialized the API in the proper way :

Gradle:

```
//library required for search
implementation("com.tomtom.online:sdk-search:2.4264")



android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="OnlineSearch.Key"
            android:value="your-tomtom-key" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have a proper API key inside the AndroidManifest.xml file. Given above you can start playing with TomTom Search API in three steps:

1. Create the SearchAPI object:

   ```
   val searchApi = OnlineSearchApi.create(applicationContext)!!
   ```
2. Create the Search query object:

   ```
   val text = "Berlin"
   val searchQuery = FuzzySearchQueryBuilder.create(text).build()
   ```
3. Call Search API and catch the results inside a listener:

   ```
   searchApi.search(searchQuery, object: FuzzySearchResultListener {
       override fun onSearchResult(response: FuzzySearchResponse?) {
           Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }

       override fun onSearchError(error: SearchError?) {
           Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }
   })
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given answer, that is now deprecated, here is the new equivalent:

```
    private val searchApi = OnlineSearchApi.create(application, TOMTOM_API_KEY)

    val term = "Berlin"
    
    searchApi.search(FuzzySearchSpecification.Builder(term).build(), object : FuzzyOutcomeCallback {
                        override fun onError(error: SearchException) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onError: ", error)
                        }
            
                        override fun onSuccess(fuzzyOutcome: FuzzyOutcome) {
                            for (fuzzyDetails in fuzzyOutcome.fuzzyDetailsList)
                                fuzzyDetails.apply { // process results (here we just print them)                               
                                  Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: fuzzyDetails = $fuzzyDetails")
                                }
                              }
                            })
```